# How to get the IP of the new instances after scaling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I would like to get the IPs only of the new instances that Terraform has created after updating some existing infraestructure.

I have the next resource instance:

```
resource "aws_instance" "masters" {
    count = "${var.masters_count}"
    ami = "${var.aws_centos_ami}"
    instance_type = "t2.medium"
    ......
    availability_zone = "eu-west-1b"

    root_block_device {
      delete_on_termination = "${var.volume_delete_on_termination}"
    }

    tags {
            Name = "master-${count.index}"
        }
}
```

If I use the next "local-exec" command, it writes all the masters instances IPs on a file:

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
    command =  "echo \"${join("\n", aws_instance.masters.*.private_ip)}\" >> ../ansible-provision/inventory/hosts.ini"
}
```

I deploy this infraestructure with 5 instances. Then I want to add another 3 instances, so I change the "count" to 8.

How can I get the IPs of that 3 new instances?

Comment: Why not just overwrite the Ansible hosts file rather than append to it? Is this some global hosts file to cover all instances across multiple Terraform locations? If so, why do you need that rather than a hosts file for each Terraform location?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR But what I want is the new instances, not all the instances, it is not problem of the file. Is that in aws_instances.masters.*.private_ip are all the masters IPs and not only the latest created instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

As I have some scripts that are run and cannot be made idempotent, then its easy enough to use ansible to put some additional ‘scaffolding’ around the non-idempotent elements with conditional execution of the scripts, so that they are only run once.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/terraform-tool/YVHReDbJ2Gw

Comment: How do you handle instances recreated out of Terraform (due to failed health check)?

Comment: @DusanBajic You can try to import that instances to Terraform: https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/import.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `null_resource`:

```
resource "null_resource" "ips" {
  triggers {
    ids = "${join(",", aws_instance.masters.*.id)}"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
  ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I used that... But this returns all the IPs in aws_instance.masters... I want only the instances that has created now. Imagine I have deploy 5 instances, now I change the count to 8, so they are 3 new instances created. I want the IPs of only that 3 new instances.

Comment: Write this output to a temp file and diff with the hosts.ini?

Comment: I don't think this is very clean way to do that.. I am finding some Terraform option..because terraform knows what has changed..

Comment: @AsierGomez - nope, can't do.